# PHP: Display <script> tag safely

Tags: php, xss, contenteditable

In my DB I have the following code: `&lt;script&gt;alert(1);&lt;/script&gt;`

I would like to present this in a contenteditable (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) without triggering the alert (XSS in general), displaying `<script>alert(1);</script>` and not displaying `&lt;script&gt;alert(1);&lt;/script&gt;`

I've gone through htmlspecialchars_decode, html_entity_decode etc but I can't suss out what's needed

We are using http://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/devdocs/cloud19b/Connect_PHP/Default.htm so can't make use of prepared statements. The way the data is stored is as such:

```
$objective = RNCPHP\objectives::fetch($id);
$objective->description = empty($description) ? '-':$description;
$objective->archive = 0;
$objective->save(); 
RNCPHP\ConnectAPI::commit();
```

Display just the content is fine. However if I add some break spaces (let's say it's a long piece of text) then it shows the 
 tags rather than the spaces

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. Is your data in db already HTML encoded?

Comment: It's probably better to store it without any encoding in the database (use a prepared statement to store it). Makes it much easier to handle the data. Encode/decode as needed when displaying.

Comment: Sorry - should add I am using Oracle Service Cloud where it does it by default - can't use prepared statements

Comment: the `<script>` tag has a special treatment in HTML, for example, as far as I know, it's the only tag where using a closing (`</script>`) inside a javascript string actually closes the currently open script tag instead of being left in the string. You have to choose either you display the characters that disable the script execution (`&lt;` / `&gt;`) or having the notice about XSS injection, can't have both. Note that `&lt;` should render as a `<`, if not, you should reproduce the problem here so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Actually this should work fine.

```
<?php
$var = "&lt;script&gt;alert(1);&lt;/script&gt;";

echo $var;
?>
```

Comment: This still triggers the alert

Comment: @pee2pee Misunderstood sorry. Updated

Comment: Ah yes - I remember now - sorry, have updated the question. if I add loads of line breaks, it just displays the <br> tags instead